# Nightwatch.js click choose file

Tags: node.js, file-upload, nightwatch.js

Everyone!

about two days trying to find solution to choose the image file for upload using `nightwatch.js`

Code looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    'File Upload': function (client) {
        client
          .url('http://myurl.com')
          .click('#selector')
          .end();
    }
};
```

we clicked on drag and drop so something like this `.setValue('input#fileUpload', require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/testfile.jpg'))` can't be exists. And

```
.keys(client.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
.keys(client.Keys.ENTER)
```

not works for this finder window:

[image: here is the screen]

I need something like `sendKeys()` in Selenium to choose the file from finder. Nightwatch.js `.keys()` works only for internet browser (Firefox for me) window. I need for popup finder to choose the file.

- Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Are you heard about online image sharing ,igmur/photobucket, upload the image then save the URL in your 'globals', for example we will have a file images.js in "globals_path":

```
    module.exports ={
      image1: 'www.imgur.com/iamge1',
      image2: 'www.imgur.com/iamge2',
         }
```

And in your test :

```
    module.exports = {
    'File Upload': function (client) {
        const images = client.images;
        client
          .url('http://myurl.com')
          .click('#choose-button')
          .setValue('#txt-path',iamges.image1)
          .click('#submit-button');
          .end();
    }
   };
```